# CiviCRM - Installing on Wordpress Hosted in AWS DB Error

Tags: wordpress, aws

I was testing out CiviCRM as part of a project I am working on and decided to host it in AWS on a WordPress site.  After downloading the newest version (5.10.4), I then uploaded the Zip file to my site.  I activated the plugin and proceeded to install CiviCRM accordingly.

To make my life easier, I created a new user with admin permissions and created a separate database for CiviCRM.  So far, so good.  I kick off the installation and everything shows up as good and the message you get post install pops up letting you know about settings, etc.  Shortly after this message appears, I get the dreaded db error message due to a syntax issue.

I looked at the logs and noticed that there is a fatal error that is one part syntax and another part where the actual tables don't seem to be within the database that CiviCRM created during installation.  I have tried a few different variants, such as older versions of CiviCRM, some cases where I did not create the separate database and user which spun off different errors, but there seems to be a theme of some type of syntax error **(Mind you, I am not writing this SQL, the application is generating it)**.  Also, the tables this is referencing, don't seem to be anywhere in the MySQL database, which is confusing to me.  See below for a snip of the log file with what I am receiving.  Any assistance or advice you all can give as to why this is occurring and how I can possibly remedy it?

Thank you in advance!

```
Mar 02 23 : 46 : 59 [info] Creating canary TABLE Mar 02 23 : 47 : 05 [info] $FATAL Error Details = Array([callback] = > Array([0] = > CRM_Core_Error [1] = > handle) [code] = > - 2 [message] = > DB Error: syntax error [mode] = > 16 [debug_info] = > SELECT v.label AS label, v.name AS value, v.grouping AS grouping FROM civicrm_option_value v
    ,civicrm_option_group g WHERE v.option_group_id = g.id
    AND g.name = 'languages'
    AND g.is_active = 1
    AND v.is_active = 1
    AND (
        v.component_id IS NULL
        OR v.component_id IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM civicrm_component
            WHERE name IN (
                    "CiviEvent"
                    ,"CiviContribute"
                    ,"CiviMember"
                    ,"CiviMail"
                    ,"CiviReport"
                    ,"CiviPledge"
                    )
            )
        ) ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value v, civicrm_option_group g WHERE  v.o' at line 1] [type] = > DB_Error [user_info] = > SELECT v.label AS label, v.name AS value, v.grouping AS grouping FROM civicrm_option_value v
    ,civicrm_option_group g WHERE v.option_group_id = g.id
    AND g.name = 'languages'
    AND g.is_active = 1
    AND v.is_active = 1
    AND (
        v.component_id IS NULL
        OR v.component_id IN (
            SELECT id
            FROM civicrm_component
            WHERE name IN (
                    "CiviEvent"
                    ,"CiviContribute"
                    ,"CiviMember"
                    ,"CiviMail"
                    ,"CiviReport"
                    ,"CiviPledge"
                    )
            )
        ) ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value v, civicrm_option_group g
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it mysql 8? Grouping is a reserved word in mysql 8 and civicrm doesn't officially support it yet.

Comment: This was the problem for me.